# Setting time zone for tests via protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, webdriver, protractor

In  my protractor test time in firefox displays bad(difference 2 hours between time in field on web site opened in firefox and system time). When I reproduce test manually-there is no problem.
My question the next: How can I run protractor test with custom(system) timezone? What should I write in capabilities?

```
capabilities: {
'browserName': '<BROWSER>',
version: '',
```

'timeZone': 'Europe/Minsk' doesn't work.
Problem reproduced only automatically and only with firefox.

Comment: where does your test get the time from?  If you show us some of the code that displays the time that is the problem, it will help us figure out a solution.

Comment: I run my test. I firefox opens web site. From the field of the web site i gets value(val4)                                                                                                           
 var row4 = element(by.repeater('metadata_field in metadata_models').row(4));
        row4.all(by.css('.time-parts input')).get(0).getAttribute("value").then(function(val4) {
          var now = new Date();
          expect(val4).to.be.within(now.getHours() - 1, now.getHours() + 1);

Comment: Please edit your question to add that source code, it's very difficult to read in the comment.
In any case, your response suggests that the time is what's displayed by the application.
Have you tried "timezone" instead of "timeZone"?

Comment: You are right. Time displayed by app and code of test isn't  important. Yes, I tried 'timezone' instead 'timeZone'. May be this way requires to use some external libraries?

Comment: After some other reading....I don't know if this will work, but perhaps try setting timezone value to a GMT offset.  e.g. GMT+13

Comment: you mean:  'timezone': 'GMT' ?

Comment: with an offset to match your target timezone, so the capability would be: 'timezone': 'GMT+13' (or whatever number is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this name `time-zone`, e.g.:

```
capabilities: {
"time-zone": "Europe/Minsk",
"browserName": "firefox",
"version": "30"
}
```

Comment: Unfornunatly it works only for Sauce Labs configuration.